# Having trouble using infinite FlatList together with a search

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-native-flatlist

So I'm listing some D&D creatures using a FlatList and I'm trying to implement a search bar where the user can get straight to what they're looking for.

```
function LandingPage() {

    const [referencesList, setReferencesList] = useState([])
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <ReferenceItem name={`${item.name} CR: ${item.challenge_rating}`} key={item.slug} index={item.slug}/>
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('/', {
            params: {
                fields: ['slug', 'name', 'challenge_rating'].join(),
                limit: 100,
                ordering: 'slug',
                search,
                page
            }
        }).then( response => {
            setReferencesList([...referencesList, ...response.data.results])
        }).catch( error => 
            console.log(error) 
        )
    }, [search, page])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <PageHeader title="Monsters List">
                <SearchReferences search={setSearch}/>
            </PageHeader>
                <FlatList
                    data={referencesList}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={40}
                    onEndReached={() => setPage(page + 1)}
                />
        </View>
    )
}

export default LandingPage
```

The thing is, every time I try to search for something, it actually adds the result to the list I already have. I tried to solve this issue like this:

```
.then( response => {
        let referencesResults = search === '' ? response.data.results : [...referencesList, ...response.data.results]
        setReferencesList(referencesResults)
})
```

But now when I search for something and then wipe my search, it doesn't go back to the initial state of my list. Can someone help me with that? Or at least point me to some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because here

```
setReferencesList([...referencesList, ...response.data.results])
```

you're appending your new results to the entire existing list, without deduplicating it.

It kind of looks like what you want is just

```
setReferencesList(response.data.results)
```

unless you'd like to cache previously returned results, which would require some additional logic.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's appending, I need that for the pagination to work, but I also need the search to work, so I'm kinda stuck in this problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would clearing the list when the search input changes (before making the api call) solve the problem?

Comment: It did solved it. Got some troubles with the api call, but I'm gonna look into it and if nothing works maybe I'll post another question